# What’s a better way to word “times are hard”

Tags: phrase-requests

In a sentence it would be “Even when ___, she remained persistent”

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Although you're getting answers, please review the [phrase-request help](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/phrase-requests/info) and give some more details about the phrase you need. In particular, please define "better" in your question title. How will you judge a particular phrase as "better"? Please [edit] all relevant data into your question. Thanks.

Comment: The variety of answers ranges from colloquial to formal, so it would be useful to know what tone or audience you are aiming for.

Comment: I don’t see anything wrong with “Even when times were hard, she remained persistent.”

Comment: Maybe “hard times” is not the right description for what you have in mind?  What situation are you thinking of?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the context, but *the going got tough* is a choice for something more colloquial.

> He was the one who had taught her to pick herself up **when the going
> got tough** and get right back in there. (Friends for Life; Carol Smith; Little Brown, Great Britian, 1995)

[OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/79750?rskey=md8j2O&result=1&isAdvanced=true#eid1110906080)

> P4. Originally U.S. Proverb. ***when the going gets tough, the tough
> get going***: pressure or adversity acts as a stimulus to those of
> strong character. Also with variation of the main clause, frequently
> with humorous intent.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a slightly antiquated expression to express the same idea:

> Even when fortune did not favor, she remained persistent.

Comment: An even more literary formulation would run:
Her persistency did not succumb to the arrows of fortune.

Answer (score 0):

> Even when **faced with adversity**, she remained persistent